# Как заменить перечисления на массивы указателей на строки?

Tags: c

Здесь вводится первая и вторая дата, если первая дата предшествует второй, то выводится 1, если вторая дата предшествует первой, то выводится 0.
Нужно заменить перечисления на массивы указателей на строки, не понятно как это осуществить, пожалуйста, подскажите.

```
   enum month { January = 1, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December }; //список месяцев



    month Get_m(int n) { // функция определения месяца 
        switch (n) {
        case 1: return January;
        case 2: return February;
        case 3: return March;
        case 4: return April;
        case 5: return May;
        case 6: return June;
        case 7: return July;
        case 8: return August;
        case 9: return September;
        case 10: return October;
        case 11: return November;
        case 12: return December;
        }
    }
    
    int func(int d1, int d2, int m1, int m2, int y1, int y2) {
        month g = Get_m(m1);
        month f = Get_m(m2);
        if (y1 < y2) { // выяснение какая дата первее
            return 1;
        }
        else if (y1 > y2) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            if (g < f) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (g > f) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                if (d1 < d2) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if (d1 > d2) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    void main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
        int d1, d2, m1, m2, y1, y2;
        printf("Введите первый день, первый месяц и первый год "); //ввод дат
        scanf_s("%d %d %d", &d1, &m1, &y1);
        printf("Введите второй день, второй месяц и второй год ");
        scanf_s("%d %d %d", &d2, &m2, &y2);
        printf("Результат: %d", func(d1, d2, m1, m2, y1, y2));
    }
```

Comment: `char const * strMonth [ ] = { [ January ] = "January" , ... } ;`

Comment: Так надо по заданию? Просто год*10 + месяц + день (например) и сравнить числа

Comment: @Виктор ваша формула неправильная. Чтобы не было пересечения нужно `год*10000+месяц*100+день` чтобы дата получилась как `20221213`

Comment: @DmitryK Я подход обрисовал - принцип, а реализацию пусть сам подумает:)

Comment: Так нужно по заданию

Comment: @AlexGlebe Спасибо за ответ, не могли бы уточнить куда нужно вставить это строку и что с ней сделать? "константа "January" не является переменной" - такая ошибка

Comment: я не знаю вашего задания и не знаю зачем вам эта строка. если срочно надо заменить перечисление на строку то так : `strMonth [ m ]`

Answer (score 0):

Для функции сравнения массив указателей на строки не нужен. Но в принципе

```
const char* MonthName[ ] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

// или так, чтобы индексы месяцев начинались с единицы
const char* MonthName[ ] = { "", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
```

Строка может понадобиться если вы захотите сделать красивый вывод типа `10 Января 2022 меньше 11 Января 2022`.
А вашу функцию можно немного переделать. В ней есть небольшой недочет - что она выдаст, если даты окажутся одинаковыми? Если решить этот вопрос, то можно немного упростить.

```
int func(int d1, int d2, int m1, int m2, int y1, int y2) 
{
        if (y1 < y2)  // выяснение какая дата первее
            return 1;
        else if (y1 > y2)
            return 0;
        
        if (m1 < m2) 
            return 1;
        else if (m1 > m2)
            return 0;

        if (d1 < d2)
            return 1;
        else if (d1 > d2)
            return 0;
          
        return -1; // если даты равны
}
```

И ещё один момент - вероятно нужно проверять корректность введенной даты. Чтобы не сравнивать 78.18.2022 с -55.-99.-2022
Проверять надо диапазоны:

- дни от 1 до 31
- месяцы от 1 до 12
- год в принципе может быть любой, если считать отрицательные числа как до н.э
- количество дней в месяце март - 31, апрель - 30
- количество дней в феврале (високосный год или нет)

Comment: в языке Си нужно добавить `=` : `MonthName[ ]={ "January",` но боюсь автор компилит в плюсах.

Comment: Исправил, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и комментарии. Мне нужно каким-то неведомым образом именно заменить одно на другое. Да, программа не совершенна, и, как мне кажется, перечисления тут вовсе лишние, потому что можно и не спрашивать Get_m(), чтобы получить цифру месяца, а сразу идти с ней дальше, однако по заданию нужно было так. Теперь же по заданию нужно заменить перечисление enum на массивы указателей

Comment: Заменить в чем? В сравнении? - не получится, т.к. сравнивать будете индексы строк в массиве. Можно заменить только при выводе. Ну или перечисление можно подставлять в качестве индекса массива - тоже своего рода "замена" `MonthName[ January ]`

Comment: @DmitryK Пожалуйста, не могли бы поподробнее рассказать про последнее(MonthName[ January ])?

Comment: Ну вы оставляете в коде свой `enum month { January = 1, February, ...` и добавляете массив названий `const char* MonthName[ ] = { "", "January", "February", ...`. Далее в программе используете в качестве индекса массива названий значение из перечисления `printf("Месяц: %s", MonthName[ January ] );`. Т.е. в данном случае `MonthName[ January ] == MonthName[ 1 ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1

```
int func(int d1, int d2, int m1, int m2, int y1, int y2) {
    return (y2 < y1) ? 1 : (y2 > y1) ? 0 :
        (m2 < m1) ? 1 : (m2 > m1) ? 0 :
        (d2 < d1) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

Вариант 2

```
int func(int d1, int d2, int m1, int m2, int y1, int y2) {
    return y1*10000+m1*100+d1 > y2*10000+m2*100+d2;
    }
```

При совпадении дат оба варианта выводят 0.